# PHP & Composer: Runtime check if class is autoloadable

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

Recently I decided to upgrade some projects from my own (...) autoloader solution to a Composer PSR-4 autoloader. My code already followed PSR-4 so, no big deal there.

On a specific case, I had the following code:

```
public static function isAutoLoadable($className)
{

    $className = ltrim($className, "\\");
    $file = $GLOBALS["Path"] . "/src/" . str_replace("\\", "/", $className) . ".php";
    if (false !== stream_resolve_include_path($file))
        return $file;

    return false;

}
```

It allowed me to check whatever a given class name could be loaded, without actually trying to load it and result on a PHP `Class * not found` error.

Use case: 
    I'm currently using it to replace controllers that by some reason couldn't be found with a generic error one, avoiding an App crash and just telling the user something went wrong... then extra internal logging is done.

A function would be good since I can call it before trying to load a controller... I don't want this behavior to spread to any other classes on the app

**So my question is**: Is there a equivalent way to check if Composer is able to autoload some class without forcing it to load it and cause an error? -- So I can take further actions in case the class wasn't found?

Comment: I'm currently using it to replace controllers that by some reason couldn't be found with a generic error one, avoiding an App crash and just telling the user something went wrong... then extra internal logging is done. A function would be good since I can call it before trying to load a controller... I don't want this behavior to spread to any other classes on the app...